# How can I return column title within data.frame only if it contains a value of interest?

Tags: r, rgui

I have a data.frame containing multiple columns made up of `TRUE` and `FALSE` logical answers, as so:

```
>` .    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8
 [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
`
```

I am trying to pull out only the titles of the columns where `TRUE` exists. For example here, I would get `X4, X6, X7` and `X8` out, but all others excluded.

For context, `TRUE` indicates a cell is responding to stimuli at that particular time point. I only need to know if the cell responds at all (i.e. `TRUE` exists in the column at least once), not when the cell responds.

Thank you in advance for any help regarding this!

Comment: What you show doesn't look like a data.frame. Please use correct terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
colnames(M)[colSums(M) >= 1]
```

The `colSums` will sum the `TRUE` values, which can then be compared against a value of 1 to extract the column names.

Example:

```
M <- matrix(FALSE, nrow = 4, ncol = 5, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("X", 1:5)))
M[cbind(c(1, 2, 3, 4), c(2, 2, 4, 5))] <- TRUE
M
#         X1    X2    X3    X4    X5
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
colnames(M)[colSums(M) >= 1]
# [1] "X2" "X4" "X5"
```

This approach would work whether you are dealing with a `matrix` or a `data.frame`.

Comment: Thank-you! This works perfectly. And yes, I meant matrix, not data frame - I'm a biologist and still get the jargon a tad off sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> names(ddf)[sapply(ddf, any)]
[1] "X4" "X6" "X7" "X8"
```

Answer (score 0):

For a matrix `m`, you can do some column indexing

```
> unique(colnames(m)[col(m)[m]])
[1] "X4" "X6" "X7" "X8"
```

Or you could use the `as.factor` argument in `col`

```
> unique(col(m, as.factor=TRUE)[m])
[1] X4 X6 X7 X8
Levels: X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
```

Originally I thought that was a matrix, but now I see it might be a data frame.  So here are two possible data frame methods for a data frame `d`

```
> names(Filter(length, Map(which, d)))
[1] "X4" "X6" "X7" "X8"
```

And another one.  This one doesn't use a loop like the `Map` option above

```
> names(d)[intersect(seq(d), col(d)[unlist(d)])]
[1] "X4" "X6" "X7" "X8"
```